# Limit JOIN to 1

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I am trying to pick out `Shop`s with the specified `$item_id`.

An `Item` can have multiple `Image`s, but I only want the *first one*.

The current code gives me only the first image, but it duplicates the item as many times as there are images.

Here's the code:

```
$shops = Shop::with(array('items' => function($query) use ($item_id) {

                    $query->select('items.id', 'items.name', 'items_images.path AS image');
                    $query->join('items_images', 'items.id', '=', 'items_images.item_id');
                    $query->where('items.id', '=', $item_id);

                }))
                ->get(array('shops.id', 'shops.shop_name', 'shops.lat', 'shops.lng'));
```

And the current output:

[image]

How can I avoid getting all the duplicates?

Comment: what determines the first one? i mean you could add a group by but i don't know if you have any specific requirement for what image to show (the group by is free to choose which row it displays)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that. The first one is the one where `main = 1`

Comment: i dont see a main in the results? couldn't you just specify that on the JOIN?

Comment: It's not in my `SELECT`, that's why you don't see it in the results.

How do I specify that in the JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work.. I haven't done much at all with this syntax but I think this is how it would work (assuming main is in the items_images table)

```
$shops = Shop::with(array('items' => function($query) use ($item_id) 
{

    $query->select('items.id', 'items.name', 'items_images.path AS image');
    $query->join('items_images', function($join)
    {
         $join->on('items.id', '=', 'items_images.item_id')
              ->where('items_images.main', '=', 1);
    })
    $query->where('items.id', '=', $item_id);
}))->get(array('shops.id', 'shops.shop_name', 'shops.lat', 'shops.lng'));
```

Found the [**DOCS**](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins) on it... if you want to include it in the JOIN then it looks like you have to add a where to the JOIN